# Cast of a C# object to string in delphi

Tags: c#, delphi, object, types, casting

I'm converting a c# project to delphi XE5 and I'm stuck on a (i believe) simple task.

```
public void TransferFile(object o, Stream stream)
{
    string s = o as string;
    if (s != null)
    { do something }
    else { do something else }
}
```

where o contains an handle of an object (in this case its value is 689520929) and the cast to string reports null, which is the expected result.

I translated it in delphi as for the following:

```
procedure TransferFile(o: OleVariant; stream: TFileStream);
var
  s: string;
begin
  s:= IntToStr(o);
  if (s <> '') then do something
  else do something else
end;
```

In this case casting the variant as string reports the number representation (689520929), which leads the program flow to a different behaviour.

Help appreciated :)

Comment: Use `VarType` to detect the type held in the variant

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't make much sense. There's no integer-to-string conversion in the C# code, so there shouldn't be an integer-to-string conversion in the Delphi code. But it's hard to say whether translating `object` to `OleVariant` is the best approach here in the first place, since there's no indication who calls the procedure, what types are permissible, and what else the procedure does with it.

Comment: It's also pretty odd to use TFileStream. Why limit yourself to files? No benefit of doing so. But without any context it is hard to give you good advice. Code is never translated in total isolation.

Comment: Olevariant is the best representation of a object datatype I got actually.

Comment: Olevariant is the best representation of a object datatype I got  in delphi actually. By the way Vartype would always bring the numeric representation of what's stored in the variant so the string would always be different from ''

Comment: About TFileStream is a side problem will use a Stream instead :-)

Comment: Unless you can specify what you want the function to do, how can you write it? You do need to decide on what should want this function to do. VarType is the way to determine what's in the variant. Whether or not a variant is the right type is unclear. I've voted to close the question because of all these doubts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`VarIsStr()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Variants.VarIsStr) to check if an `(Ole)Variant` holds a string value or not, eg:

```
procedure TransferFile(o: OleVariant; stream: TFileStream);
var
  s: string;
begin
  if VarIsStr(o) then begin
    s := VarToStr(o);
    // do something...
  end else begin
    // do something else...
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Marco,  VarIsStr is built on VarType which you claimed was not appropriate. Leads me to believe that you don't have a good understanding of variants and would do well to brush up on them.